# Listen/Look, Jeff, I don't know who told you that

Tags: difference, idiomatic-language

Are "listen" and "look" interchangeable in contexts like this? This is a phone conversation if that makes any difference.

*Listen/Look, Jeff, I don't know who told you that, but it's not true.*

Comment: Nobody cares that much about the *literal* meanings of the different "verbs of perception" in such contexts. It could just as easily have been expressed as  ***See here now,** Jeff,...* (where even if Jeff was actually blind from birth, no-one would normally think that was an "unusual" usage).

Comment: They're not interchangeable, but the differences are not significant.